# How to use ILIKE for multiple values in single column in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to use ILIKE for multiple values in single column.

This is the solution for multiple values without using like condition:

```
Project.where(name: ["Arvind Oasis", "Prestige Jindal City"])
```

In this example, it is taking the exact matches in my database. but i want to take similar matches for all the values.

How to use **ILIKE** for multiple values **["Arvind Oasis", "Rajkumar Jindal City"]**

For single values i can use like this,

```
Project.where("name ILIKE ?", "%Prestige Kumar%")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use:

```
Project.where("name ILIKE ANY (array[?])", ["%Arvind Oasis%", "%Prestige Jindal City%", "%XXXX%"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try postgres [SIMILAR TO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html) operator like below

> Project.where("name similar to
>   '%(Arvind\sOasis|Rajkumar\sJindal\sCity)%'")